# How does $L_1$ or $L_2$ regularization affect bias?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, bias, regularization

Regularization is used to decrease variance. This must mean that it affects bias. How?

To be precise, let's say you have a data matrix $A=(x_{ij})$ whose first column is all $1$'s. Say that our model is $Y=A\beta+\epsilon$, where $\beta$ is some vector, and where $\epsilon$ has a multivariate normal distribution with mean $0$, and variance-covariance matrix $\sigma^2I$.

Let $\hat Y_{reg}=A{\hat \beta_{reg}}$ be the usual OLS; and let $\hat Y_{L_i}=A{\hat \beta_{L_i}}$ be the prediction using $L_i$ for $i=1,2$.

Then $\hat Y_{reg}$ is an unbiased estimator of $E(Y)=A\beta$.

Presumably, since $\hat Y_{L_i}$ is supposed to have a lower variance (or to be precise $V(\hat Y_{L_i}-Y)<V(\hat Y_{reg}-Y)$), then it's supposed to have greater bias.

What is its bias, then? What is $E(\hat Y_{L_i})$ for $i=1,2$, explicitly?

(Bonus points for a reference or quick proof that $V(\hat Y_{L_i}-Y)<V(\hat Y_{reg}-Y)$, which I've always had a hard time grasping.)

Comment: In a nutshell, regularization works by biasing coefficients towards 0.